# Run an external program with php

Tags: php, linux, command, exec

i have a problem with php ! i want to run an external program with php . this program work in command line and in linux platform . so it must be work just fine . but i try more time and i can't run it . so what's wrong !
this is the link of the program : http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/
and this is the command which work fine in command line and not the case in php :

```
./fet --inputfile=Hopwood.fet --outputdir=out
```

and this is the php code :

```
<?php
`./fet --inputfile=Hopwood.fet --outputdir=out`
?>
```

i hope to solve this pb .
thanks in advance ..

**Update** i upload the executable program and the Hopwood.fet file for you try it ..
this is a link :
http://rapidshare.com/files/454756427/fet.tar.gz

Comment: It might help us if you formatted your code so we could see exactly what your trying to run.

Comment: are you sure you're running ./fet in the correct subdirectory?

Comment: all right , i go to edit my question now .

Comment: As @stillstanding says. So you might like to try using the absolute path to your binary. eg. `/usr/bin/local/fet --inputfile=Hopwood.fet --outputdir=out` where `/usr/bin/local` is the directory containing `fet`

Comment: @treffynnon i try but no way !

Comment: hey, that's not php code! I bet you'll get fatal error.

Comment: @silent backticks are a perfectly acceptable substitute for `shell_exec` See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: haha, then I should check my fact. thanks

Comment: is there anything, in your error log?

Comment: @silent you can try the program i compile it and upload it , check the question ..

Comment: wait a minute. I think something's missing here. Have you try to run this program from shell on your hosting server? or you did run it ONLY on your own linux desktop / laptop / etc / something else not from your current server?

Comment: the server is my laptop , i use lamp server and the command work fine in terminal ..

Answer (score 2):

try doing it in full path:

```
/path/to/installed/fet --inputfile=/path/to/your/Hopwood.fet --outputdir=/path/to/your/out
```

so you'll end up executing:

```
exec("/path/to/installed/fet --inputfile=/path/to/your/Hopwood.fet --outputdir=/path/to/your/out");
```

Also, make sure running process has ability to write to your `/path/to/your/out`

**UPDATE**

To make thing's clearer, please try to run this command:

```
exec("/path/to/installed/fet --inputfile=/path/to/your/Hopwood.fet --outputdir=/path/to/your/out 2> /tmp/fet.error.log", $output, $status);

echo "status: " . $status;
echo "output: " . implode("\n", $output);

if(file_exists("/tmp/fet.error.log"))
{
  echo "Error Log: " . file_get_contents("/tmp/fet.error.log");
}
```

**UPDATE**

as @mkotwd told on another answer (after trying debug code, above). The problem is because `fet` trying to access X Server. So, as @mkotwd answer's the solution is add:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and the command become:

```
exec("export DISPLAY=:0 && fet --inputfile=Hopwood.fet --outputdir=out");
```

Comment: unfortunately , i set the right permission and the whole path but not work !

Comment: If the permissions are correct (you need execute on the program and on the input/output dirs and read + execute permission on 'fet' and any resources it requires) and you've checked that the webserver is not running chroot and you've not disabled execution functionality then it will work. Go back and try again.

Comment: @symcbean thanks , if you can try the program , i set the link below

Comment: nice : this is the output :status: 1output: Error Log: fet: cannot connect to X server

Comment: haha! as I though. this problem tell us that your application require X server and that's not usually available on hosting server: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System.  I'm sorry, I can't help you anymore, if it's the problem.

Comment: they have mailing list. Maybe you should ask there about your current situation: http://www.lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/mailinglist.html

Comment: nice, pick your's as best answer and welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running fet from a local installation (based on the ./fet command you've posted).

You need to add the location of your fet installation to your PATH variable.

On a linux system, edit your ~/.bashrc, and add the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/mkotwd/fet
```

if /home/mkotwd/fet is where you've installed fet.

Alternately, you can also make a directory ~/bin, add it to your PATH as explained above, and create a symlink ~/bin/fet that points to your fet executable. This is the recommended solution because you won't have to add to PATH the directory of every local command you might want to run in the future, you can just create symlinks to each executable in ~/bin

You might also want to check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php for calling details, security considerations, and miscellaneous tips posted by users who've used the command for various tasks.

Comment: yes i try all this but is not work , the exec command return the 0 int if done , fyi the function return 1 value !!

Answer (score 0):

Check `php -i | less` for:

- [safe_mode](http://php.net/manual/de/features.safe-mode.php)
- [configuration of suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html), if installed

It might be one of those security measures, which prevents those critical commands (or both).

Comment: the exec command work right for other program that i try , like resize with inkscape and mkdir command, ls .. the safe mode is off !!

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add this command before :

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

so the code become :

```
<?php
exec("export DISPLAY=:0 && fet --inputfile=Hopwood.fet --outputdir=out");
?>
```

Comment: You could've mentioned that fet tries to launch a window by default.

Comment: @Amey, you should read the whole comment and question and answers ;)