# PHP won't execute a python file

Tags: python, php, shell

I've been getting this problem for a little while now.
The thing is that i have an HTML form proceed by PHP which looks like that:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "tablename");
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $shorturl = str_replace(['/', 'https:', 'http:'], '', $url);
    $iconpath = shell_exec("python3 /home/favicon.py {$url}");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO links (url, shorturl, iconpath) values ('{$url}', '{$shorturl}', '{$iconpath}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
/*
header('Location: /');
exit;
*/
?>
```

This code is supposed to extract the given URL from the form, execute python file that downloads favicon of the site and insert the data into a MySQL table.
Python code:

```
import sys
import requests

url = sys.argv[1]
img_data = requests.get(f'{url}/favicon.ico').content
iconpath = '/home/favicon.png'
with open(iconpath, 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
print(iconpath)
```

It all works fine except for the favicon part. When i run the python file from shell, it works fine. When i run it from PHP interactive console by the exact same code written in the form handler, it works fine. But it just won't run properly in the handler, because even when i try to debug it like

```
echo $iconpath;
```

it doesn't actually show anything in there. What can i do with it?

**P.S.** the code actually inserts $url and $shorturl variables into the database, so i said it all works fine except the shell_exec part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call python script with php (windows xampp server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384315/call-python-script-with-php-windows-xampp-server)

Comment: @MarkusZeller it doesn't. as i said, the code totally works in PHP interactive console, but won't work in the handler

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. The user that your web server runs as (which will be different from you using the command line) doesn't have the right permissions to run the Python code. That said, it's such a simple piece of Python code, why not do it all in PHP?

Comment: The error as to why it doesn't run likely shows up in your server logs.

Comment: In addition to what @TangentiallyPerpendicular said about permissions, you have a PATH variable set, the web server likely does not. Specify the full path to `python3` A more accurate duplicate target is possibly this one, but I'm out of close votes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456961/run-an-external-program-with-php

Comment: You should also do `$url = escapeshellarg($url)` in case the URL contains characters that have special meaning to the shell.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular just got it done using PHP, ty for the advice :) i didn't actually know you can access other urls using it